# Matplotlib - Axis limits different to tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a graph `displayer` which allows the user to set their own number of ticks per axis, upon drawing a graph with 6 ticks the limits of this axes are considered `0 - 1` (So the ticks would be `0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1` while the actual tick labels range from `0 - 15` on the `y` axis and `0 - 13` on the `x` axis. How can I make the axis limits uniform to what the labels say? Reason I need this is that I need to perform vertex snapping to grid corners and need to calculate when ticks intersect on the `x` and `y` axis and cannot do this effectively if I can't get tick locations that are relative to the node positions. Here is the code I am using to set the ticks:

```
ax = plt.gca()
loc = plticker.LinearLocator(numticks = intervals + 2)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.grid(which='major', axis='both', linestyle='--')
```

Comment: Where do 0-15 and 0-13 come from? Can you clarify what you mean by "making the axis limits uniform to what the labels say"?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The 0-15 and 0-13 are the min and max of the y and x axis (this will change depending on the size of the graph). What I want is for the axis limits to be the same as the min and max displayed by the labels